# Why is firefox connecting to these servers on startup?

Tags: firefox

When I startup Firefox without any webpage it connects to all these hosts:

```
$ netstat -anp | grep ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 [REDACTED]:56728      52.41.213.214:443       ESTABLISHED 28943/firefox       
tcp        0      0 [REDACTED]:35370      117.18.237.29:80        ESTABLISHED 28943/firefox       
tcp        0      0 [REDACTED]:35380      117.18.237.29:80        ESTABLISHED 28943/firefox       
tcp        0      0 [REDACTED]:53882      52.89.175.187:443       ESTABLISHED 28943/firefox       
tcp        0      0 [REDACTED]:54558      172.217.24.138:443      ESTABLISHED 28943/firefox       
tcp        0      0 [REDACTED]:33106      23.219.39.25:80         ESTABLISHED 28943/firefox       
tcp        0      0 [REDACTED]:35368      117.18.237.29:80        ESTABLISHED 28943/firefox       
tcp        0      0 [REDACTED]:40282      52.42.232.148:443       ESTABLISHED 28943/firefox       
tcp        0      0 [REDACTED]:44278      52.42.50.122:443        ESTABLISHED 28943/firefox       
tcp        0      0 [REDACTED]:53068      54.230.174.55:443       ESTABLISHED 28943/firefox       
tcp        0      0 [REDACTED]:43654      172.217.31.163:80       ESTABLISHED 28943/firefox
```

I'm curious why its connecting to all these servers even though there is no webpage open. The only thing open is default homepage of firefox. If I inspect the network on that page, there are no calls.

Comment: Use wireshark and capture the traffic.

Comment: You need also to take into account any plugin/extension you have installed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MozillaZine's article [Connections established on startup](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Connections_established_on_startup_-_Firefox):

- Update checks (application, phishing sites database, add-ons blocklist, metadata for installed add-ons).
- Loading Live Bookmarks, if any.
- Home Page / pages configured to load at startup + prefetching links.
- Firefox Health Report data.

Some of these can be disabled as explained on the article.